# Akka cluster boostrapping demo doesn't work

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I'm testing [Akka Cluster Bootstrapping](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/akka-management/current/bootstrap.html)'s discovery-dns demo from [here](https://github.com/akka/akka-management/tree/master/bootstrap-joining-demo/dns-api-mesos).
I disabled the `HTTP` management part and run it on my local machine, the `application.conf` is the same except I changed the `tcp.port` when I start the second server.

I'm running those servers on my school's computers.

I started two servers and run without error, but they can't discovery node and print out those logs continuously, I tried a lot of different configurations but no luck, any help would be appreciated!

Here is a part of the logs:

```
[INFO] [05/30/2018 20:16:13.364] [simple-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.tcp://simple@127.0.0.1:2552/system/bootstrapCoordinator] Located service members with name: [simple]: []   
[INFO] [05/30/2018 20:16:13.754] [simple-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-35] [LowestAddressJoinDecider(akka://simple)] Discovered [0] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying   
[INFO] [05/30/2018 20:16:14.442] [simple-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [DnsSimpleServiceDiscovery(akka://simple)] Resolved Dns.Resolved: Resolved(simple,List(),List())
```

And this is my application.conf:

```
akka {
  loglevel = INFO
  discovery.method = akka-dns
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
remote {
  netty.tcp {
  hostname = 127.0.0.1
  port = 2551
  }
 }
management {
  http {
  hostname = 127.0.0.1
  port = 8558
}
cluster.bootstrap {     
  contact-point {
    fallback-port = 8558
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few demos, which one? Can you fix the links and provide your config

Comment: The demo is in the hyper link of the first sentence, which is :https://github.com/akka/akka-management/tree/master/bootstrap-joining-demo/dns-api-mesos